# reset html <td> tag to original color

Tags: javascript, html, calendar

I'm trying to reset an HTML `<td>` tag to it's original color using an `onclick` and then calling two javascript functions.

The first function will (hopefully) set the previously changed color.

The second function changes the selected `<td>` to a cyan background color.  (This works).  As a final step of this function I set a var hold which should the `<td>` id.

That var, (hold), should be used in the first function during the next change to revert to the original color.

I call the functions like so:  `<td onclick( clear(); changecolor(element id);) ...more stuff>`

If I've confused you, the program is a calendar and the selected date `bgcolor` turns cyan.  When another date is selected I want to change the first one back to white.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var hold;

function mouseclick(el) {
    el.style.color = "black";
    el.style.backgroundColor = "cyan";
    hold = el;
}
function clear() {

    hold.style.color = "black";
    hold.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
</script>
```

Comment: add `clear();` to the end of the `mouseclick` (before line `hold=el`).  Then in TD tag `onclick=mouseclick(element_id)`

Comment: *Invalid:* `<td onclick( clear(); changecolor(element id);) ...more stuff>`

Comment: Just cause I wrote the fiddle for fun. Here is it: http://jsfiddle.net/nW4Bm/

Answer (score 2):

You don't need two functions to revert the cell background color. The best thing to do is to use css & js together to change the appearance of a cell based on UI interaction. See the example jsfiddle I have created here: http://jsfiddle.net/rYcMT/

--Javascscript --

```
    var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
      cells[i].addEventListener('click', onClick, false);
    }


    function onClick(event){
        var el = event.target;
        var id = el.getAttribute("id");

        el.className = 'selected';

        var others = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
        var oLength = others.length;

        for(var i=0; i < oLength; i++){
         if(others[i].getAttribute("id") !== id){
             others[i].className = '';        
         }
     }
};
```

where your css looks like the following:
-- CSS --
    .calendar, tr, td {
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
    }
    .calendar td{
        background-color: white;
    }

```
.calendar td.selected{
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

-- hTML --

```
<table class="calendar">
    <tr>
        <td id="05012013">May 1</td>
        <td id="05022013">May 2</td>
        <td id="05032013">May 3</td>
        <td id="05042013">May 4</td>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="05052013">May 5</td>
        <td id="05062013">May 6</td>
        <td id="05072013">May 7</td>
        <td id="05082013">May 8</td>    
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want only one element at a time to have the color.

If so, just give the one that should be highlighted an ID that has styles set to it. Then whenever one is clicked, remove the ID from the first, and put it on the new one.

You can easily accomplish this with a "live nodeList".

```
var tds = my_table.getElementsByTagName("td");
```

You'll always be able to get the one with the ID as a property of the list. So if your ID is `"active"`, you'd do:

```
tds.active; // gives the current TD with the "active" id
```

---

***DEMO:*** http://jsbin.com/ohadej/1

So assuming you have inline handlers, like this:

```
<td onclick="changecolor(this)" ...></td>
```

And CSS like this:

```css
#my_table td {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
td#active {
    color: black;
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

Your code could look like this:

```
var tds = my_table.getElementsByTagName("td");

function changecolor(el) {
    var current = tds.active;
    if (current)
        current.id = "";

    // (tds.active || {}).id = "active"; // shorter version of the 3 lines above

    el.id = "active";
}
```

Comment: Squint!  Thanks for the demo.  It does what I'm trying to do.  The code doesn't though.